# Enforce haskell-like function declaration on javascript with eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to know if there is a lint rule that I can use to enforce this style of function declaration:

```
const requisites = 
    ensure ('The provided list of services yielded 0 services to load') (gteLength(1))

const abort =
    (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1)
    }
```

As you can see the function name is on one line and the entire function declaration is on the next line indented.
The first example is a point-free function declaration while the second is a normal arrow function.

This not only confuses the editor about indentation (VSC) but also there is no rule on eslint (as far as I know) to enforce it.

I don't even know how to search about this, so any help will be awesome.

Regards

Comment: Unless you are writing JavaScript that will only ever be seen/used by yourself or a very small group of people who are all sold on this convention, do not do this. Code is for other people to read.

Comment: It is for me and my coworkers, yes. I want to introduce them to purescript, and I want them to get used to the way of declaring functions.

Comment: Uh, that's not what I would call haskell-like.

Comment: Changing languages is a major move. Changing to a radically different and stricter type system with static types and functional purity is majorer. What problems do you have in your codebase that moving to purescript will solve?

Comment: I would call that a [hanging indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting)#Indentation_in_typesetting), but given it's not usually used in programming anywhere (especially that you force the initialiser expression in the next line) I doubt you'll find an existing VSC formatter or Eslint rule and rather will have to write your own.

Comment: @Bergi, please consider adding your comment as a response, I will accept it. At least you have named the indentation style, which is kind useful.

Comment: @Danielo515 It's not an indentation style used in programming, it's just a name I came up with so I doubt it makes a good answer. Or did you search for the term and found something useful?